# To convert Gregorian date to solar date-I showed with such errors

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datetime

i have this script for convert DateTime persian to English -i have error code.

> ```
>   public ActionResult addvisit(int docid, int visitid, string visitdatetime, string pid)
>         {
>             int intpid = 0;
>
>             if (pid != "")
>             {
>                 var p = context.Table_Patient.Where(x => x.NationalCode == pid).SingleOrDefault();
>                 if (p == null)
>                 {
>                     return Json(new { status = 2, nv = 0 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  //no NashnalCode
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     intpid = p.pkID;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             string[] vdatetime = visitdatetime.Split(' ');
>             string[] vdate = vdatetime[0].Split('/');
>             string[] vtime = vdatetime[1].Split(':');
>
>
>
>             int y = MyExtensions.PersianToEnglish(vdate[0]);
>             int m = MyExtensions.PersianToEnglish(vdate[1]);
>             int d = MyExtensions.PersianToEnglish(vdate[2]);
>             int h = MyExtensions.PersianToEnglish(vtime[0]);
>             int min = MyExtensions.PersianToEnglish(vtime[1]);
>
>             PersianCalendar a = new PersianCalendar();
>
>             DateTime a = PC.ToDateTime(y, m, d, h, min, 0, 0);
>
>             Double Duration = context.View_PerDoctorsID.Where(x => x.fkDocID == docid && x.fkVisitID == visitid).Select(x => x.Duration).Single();
>
>             Table_Visit nv = new Table_Visit();
>
>             nv.fkDocID = docid;
>             nv.SDate = a;
>             nv.EDate = a.AddMinutes(Duration);
>             if (pid == null)
>             {
>
>                 nv.fkPID = null;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 nv.fkPID = intpid;
>             }
>             nv.fkVisitStatus = 1;
>             nv.fkVTID = visitid;
>             var thisvisit = context.View_Visit.Where(x => x.fkDocID == docid && x.fkVTID == visitid && x.SDate == nv.SDate && x.EDate == nv.EDate).SingleOrDefault();
> ```
>
> i have error a =pc ?
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aONNy.png)
>
> so i have in part error list this error.
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0128  A local variable or function named 'a' is already defined in this scope hospital    D:\Cili\hospital\Controllers\HomeController.cs  266 Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'PC' does not exist in the current context hospital    D:\Cili\hospital\Controllers\HomeController.cs  266 Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Globalization.PersianCalendar' to 'System.DateTime'  hospital    D:\Cili\hospital\Controllers\HomeController.cs  273 Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'minutes' of 'Calendar.AddMinutes(DateTime, int)'  hospital    D:\Cili\hospital\Controllers\HomeController.cs  274 Active

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Qhn.png)

i define class for convert digit variable persain To English

```
 public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int PersianToEnglish(this string persianStr)
        {
            Dictionary<char, char> LettersDictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>
            {
                ['۰'] = '0',
                ['۱'] = '1',
                ['۲'] = '2',
                ['۳'] = '3',
                ['۴'] = '4',
                ['۵'] = '5',
                ['۶'] = '6',
                ['۷'] = '7',
                ['۸'] = '8',
                ['۹'] = '9',
                ['0'] = '0',
                ['1'] = '1',
                ['2'] = '2',
                ['3'] = '3',
                ['4'] = '4',
                ['5'] = '5',
                ['6'] = '6',
                ['7'] = '7',
                ['8'] = '8',
                ['9'] = '9'

            };
            foreach (var item in persianStr)
            {
                persianStr = persianStr.Replace(item, LettersDictionary[item]);
            }
            return int.Parse(persianStr);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TJmu.png)

Comment: Yes, you tried to define `a` *twice*: `PersianCalendar a = new PersianCalendar();

      DateTime a = PC.ToDateTime(y, m, d, h, min, 0, 0);`. That's why the compiler complains: is `a` of type `PersianCalendar` or `DateTime`

Comment: how can i write?

Comment: Could you, please, state the initial problem? E.g. "I have a Persian Date as a `string` in format ... e.g. `۱۴۰۲ یکشنبه ۲۸ خرداد` and I want to get `DateTime` from it 18 June 2023"

Comment: Javascript and jquery tags are somewhat incompatible with the c# tag.